# Android JSONObject becomes null when trying to send

Tags: java, android, json, stream

When I'm trying to push a `JSONObject` over a data stream, and I've built the `JSONObject` properly, but then I try and publish it to the stream it is null.

```
JSONObject position = new JSONObject();

        try {
            position.put("lat", location.getLatitude());
            position.put("lng", location.getLongitude());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("json not work");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(position) //result: {"lat":37,"lng":-122}
        pubNub.publish().message(position)//never sent, if other type it works
```

Comment: never sent, if other type it works?? explain more about this

Answer (score 0):

try `pubNub.publish().message(position.toString());`

Comment: If you stringify the JSON, you will have to parse on the other end. You should always just publish the JSON object as is.

Comment: .toString does work, but why should I have to convert it and extract on the other end? The JSON should just get sent as JSON, it's in the spec for this service